# In Java is it possible to dynamically create anonymous subclass instance given only instance of parent class?

Tags: java, reflection

In Java is it possible to dynamically create anonymous subclass instance given only instance of parent class?

The pattern code I'm trying to implement looks like this:

```
public interface IStringCarier { public String getStr(); }

public static IStringCarier introduce(Object victim, final String str) {
   // question subject
}

public class AAA { }

public static void main() {
    AAA aaa = new AAA();

    assert !(aaa instanceof IStringCarier);

    IStringCarier bbb = introduce(aaa, "HelloWorld");

    assert aaa == bbb;
    assert "HelloWorld".equals(bbb.getStr());
}
```

There're actually 2 more requirements-questions regarding this code:

(2) Not just create subclass instance, but also reassign prototype instance to the newly created instance (2nd assert in the code).

(3) Introduce the subclass to some specific interface.

I doubt this is possible, but I'm novice with Java, so...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Java, can I create an instance of an anonymous subclass from a Class object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306474/in-java-can-i-create-an-instance-of-an-anonymous-subclass-from-a-class-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are new to java, you must ask yourself why you need this functionality. Most certainly there will exist a better solution would you only describe what problem you're trying to solve.

The only approach you have (except for rewriting the bytecode) is to use [Dynamic Proxies](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html), as they are capable of implementing an interface at runtime. But using them the way you suggest wouldn't really make much sence.

> Not just create subclass instance, but also reassign prototype instance to the newly created instance

Java does not employ prototypical inheritance.

Comment: In this case I think "prototype instance" refers to the instance sent as first parameter to introduce(), rather than in some prototype inheritence sense.

Comment: If there won't be other answers, I guess, it impossible then for all three parts of my question...